# jQuery to locate an element by Attribute and Replace it's HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

JS:

```
$('.translate').on('click', function(){

    $("*").each(function() {

        $.each(this.attributes, function() {            
            if (this.name.indexOf('uloc') == 0) {

                $(this).parent().html("HELLOOOOOOOO!");

                console.log(this.name + ' has the value: ' + this.value);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="" uloc="report_problem">Report a problem</a></li>
    <li><a href="" uloc="privacy_policy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
    <li><a href="" uloc="terms_of_service">Terms of Service</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><a class="translate" locale="fr">Français</a></li>
    <li><a class="translate" locale="en">English</a></li>
</ul>
```

So on click, the text in the found elements should be replaced with Hello.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: your question is unclear? what is  `uloc`? and what actually need to happen when someone click on `Français`?

Comment: If you're going to use custom attributes you should consider using the correct form of custom attributes (in order for HTML validity): [custom `data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could a simple [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) in the first place:

```js
$('.translate').on('click', function() {

  $("[uloc]").html("HELLOOOOOOOO!");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="" uloc="report_problem">Report a problem</a></li>
    <li><a href="" uloc="privacy_policy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
    <li><a href="" uloc="terms_of_service">Terms of Service</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><a class="translate" locale="fr">Français</a></li>
    <li><a class="translate" locale="en">English</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have a problem here: `$(this).html( localisation.eval($(this).attr("uloc")));` I need the contents of the `uloc` to select from an array.

Comment: @Borsn I need some more context here, but `eval()` is most likely not necessary. I guess you have problems selecting the right localization text - so in what format are those texts?

Comment: Unless all the translation text is "HELLOOO" you will need to iterate over those elements with "uloc" as @BhushanKawadkar has shown.  Having all of the elements text changing to HELLOOOO in one command like in the example is not so useful, IMO.

Comment: @James The question only asks how to replace with "hello". So anything else is (for now) out of scope. The need for translations can be *guessed* from the comments and some identifiers, but OP never stated it in the question.

Comment: @Sirko You're absolutely correct.  I can't help reading between the lines to address "what they meant" instead of "what they asked for".  Since you can accomplish both with a tiny bit more thought and a single extra line of code, I'll take the solution that has it.

Comment: @Sirko @James It is indeed needed for translation. I store the text like this `const en = {terms_of_service:"Terms of service", privacy_policy:"Privacy Policy", }` and fetch it afterwards based on the `uloc`. Solved the problem though.

Answer (score 2):

We don't need to iterate over all elements with attribute `uloc`. jQuery will do it for us. The simplest solution can be-

```js
$('.translate').on('click', function() {
  $("[uloc]").html("HELLOOOOOOOO!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="" uloc="report_problem">Report a problem</a></li>
    <li><a href="" uloc="privacy_policy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
    <li><a href="" uloc="terms_of_service">Terms of Service</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><a class="translate" locale="fr">Français</a></li>
    <li><a class="translate" locale="en">English</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @James I will take care of it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The each function has 2 parameters: index and element that you are iterating. You can use that element to modify the html.

https://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$('.translate').on('click', function(){
    $('[uloc]').each(function(index, element)  {
        $(element).html("HELLOOOOOOOO!");                       
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is simple. When you refer to `$(this).parent().html("HELLOOOOOOOO!");`, `this` points to the attribute that you are iterating on. To avoid that, you can keep track of the element from outer loop and use that while accessing the parent element:

```js
$('.translate').on('click', function() {

  $("*").each(function() {
    // *** Remember the element, to be used later
    var element = this;

    $.each(this.attributes, function() {
      if (this.name.indexOf('uloc') == 0) {

        $(element).parent().html("HELLOOOOOOOO!");

        console.log(this.name + ' has the value: ' + this.value);
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="" uloc="report_problem">Report a problem</a></li>
  <li><a href="" uloc="privacy_policy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
  <li><a href="" uloc="terms_of_service">Terms of Service</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li><a class="translate" locale="fr">Français</a></li>
  <li><a class="translate " locale="en ">English</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works. But I have a problem here: `$(this).html( localisation.eval($(this).attr("uloc")));` I need the contents of the `uloc` to select from an array.

Comment: @Borsn I'm not sure which array you are referring to. It would help if you could edit/update the question with relevant code. Or if this is a separate question, create a new one, and share the link.

Comment: For example `uloc="terms_of_service"` needs to be the selector here `const en = {terms_of_service:"Terms of service", privacy_policy:"Privacy Policy", }`

Comment: @Borsn So you would do something like `en[$(element).attr("uloc")]` where element is the variable I have kept aside earlier.

Answer (score 1):

you can use attribute selector of jquery to find all elements having attribute `uloc` and replace it's text. see below code

```js
$(function(){
$('.translate').on('click', function(){

    $("[uloc]").each(function() {
         $(this).text("HELLOOOOOOOO!"); 
     });

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="" uloc="report_problem">Report a problem</a></li>
    <li><a href="" uloc="privacy_policy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
    <li><a href="" uloc="terms_of_service">Terms of Service</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><a class="translate" locale="fr">Français</a></li>
    <li><a class="translate" locale="en">English</a></li>
</ul>
```